# Jackson: class to JSON array

Tags: java, json, jackson, dropwizard, jackson-databind

I have a Java class like this

```
class MyClass {
    private final List<Element> myList;

    public MyClass(List<Element> aList) {
        myList = aList;
    }

    public List<Element> getThatList() {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

I am using Dropwizard to turn that class into a JSON response to an HTTP method call. Dropwizard uses Jackson under the hood.

Problem: JSON comes out like this

```
{
    "thatList":[
        {"el1prop1":1,"el1prop2":"str1"},
        {"el2prop1":2,"el2prop2":"str2"}
    ]
}
```

Basically, the instance of `MyClass` is turned into an object. The desired output, instead, is an array (basically, the value of the only key of the object)

```
[
        {"el1prop1":1,"el1prop2":"str1"},
        {"el2prop1":2,"el2prop2":"str2"}
]
```

Is there a way (using Jackson annotations or some other way) to obtain that?

Comment: Could you return `List<Element>` directly? Why is it wrapped in another class if all you want to return is the list? If that class is really necessary you could try and have `MyClass` extend `ArrayList<String>` etc. (or implement `List<String>` and delegate to the inner list while slapping some `@JsonIgnore` onto it).

Comment: The first time I tried that, Dropwizard started replying 404, so I assumed it wasn't possible. I tried again, and... it worked.